# retrieve additional informations about sonata image in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using SonataMediaBundle. Is it possible to retrieve additional informations about images in twig?

This sentence retrieve image:

```
{% media item.image, 'big' %}
```

Can I retrieve for example author, description, copyright etc.? I can set this informations in SonataAdmin.

**EDIT:**
I found solution:

```
{{item.image.description}}
```

Comment: could you please add the solution as an answer and accept it so this issue can be marked as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. To retrieve additional informations about image simply use:

```
{# image description #}
{{item.image.description}}

{# image author #}
{{item.image.authorName}}

{# etc. #}
```